# Piping PS output into a Text file

Tags: linux, ps

So what im wanting to do is pretty basic.....but im not sure how to go about it.
Lets say I have a program running, but I want to pipe the output of ps -C "ProgramXX" into a file.

Normally Running ps -C "ProgramXX" Produces something to the effect of:

```
PID TTY TIME            CMD
123 ?   00:00:00    Program1
142 ?   00:00:00    Program1
165 ?   00:00:00    Program1
221 ?   00:00:00    Program1
```

Is their any "simple" way to just get the 1st columns and 4th column (ignoring the top heading line) into a text file.

I figure you could run ps -C "Program1" >> Data.txt.....then maybe run a script to cut out the fat? This would be done in Bash btw. Maybe using grep or something.....but I wouldn't really know. This would be ran multiple times btw......so data.txt would continue to grow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can control the columns that get output by `ps`. Note that the exact commandline does vary between the various flavours of Linux/Unix but I believe the following will do what you want.

```
ps --no-headers -o pid,comm  -C "ProgramXX" >> Data.txt
```

The man page for `ps(1)` will list all of the options available to you.

Comment: This seems to be the best way, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`ps` is a swiss-army-knife of functionality. You want this

```
ps -C "ProgramXX" -o pid=,comm=
```

`-o` controls the output columns and a trailing `=` indicates that you don't want a header.

If you write it this way:

```
ps -o comm= -o pid= | grep '^ProgramXX'
```

Then it should work with most `ps` implementations. Unfortunately, `-C` is a GNUism.

Answer (score 5):

`pgrep -l Program1` will give the output you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`cut(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to do this, e.g.

```
ps -C "Program1" | cut -c1-4,20-50 | tail +1
```

With the character positions in the `-c` option of `cut` set to cut out the right fields.  `tail +1` gets everything but the first line of the output, which will trim the first line.

You could also convert it into a delimited file by adding `sed` into the pipeline with something like:

```
ps -C "Program1" | sed 's/  */,/g' | cut -d, -f1,4 | tail +1
```

Which will give you output with comma separated values.

Comment: But How would I redirect it, would i put >> after the cut or before.

Comment: @Sauron: It would be after, but see Richm's answer (and my own) for how to do this a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `cut`, I like to use `awk` because it can extract whitespace-delimited words without having to count blank spaces:

```
ps -C "Program 1" | awk '{print $1,$4}'
```

Note that `awk` would not be a good solution for output that may have a blank value in a column, or a multi-word value.